# I have a wav file of length 10 seconds, i want to segment the file in Matlab in 10 files each one second

Tags: matlab

I have read a WAV file of length 10 seconds in Matlab. I want to segment the audio file into 10 files of equal length. What should I do?

Comment: Please paste some code

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('orig.wav');

OUTPUT_FOLDER='z:/';
OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX='wave';
N_SPLIT=10;
y(end+1:end+N_SPLIT-mod(length(y),N_SPLIT),:)=0;%need to be divisible by N_SPLIT, so pad some zeros at end. 
y_parts=reshape(y,[],1,N_SPLIT);%split signal
for i=1:N_SPLIT
    filename=sprintf('%s%02d.wav',OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX,i);
    filepath=fullfile(OUTPUT_FOLDER,filename);
    y_to_write=y_parts(:,:,i);
    audiowrite(filepath,y_to_write,Fs); %save
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help...but there is a error in   audiowrite(filepath,y_to_write,Fs);

Comment: change OUTPUT_FOLDER to real folder

Comment: Thanks.I have an audio file containing 0-9 digits in Urdu Language, i want to split the audio file on basis of digits. What should i do?